# How to pass strings in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass the string from activity to other activities.
For example, tell that I have 5 activities I get a text from the second to the third to the forth to the fifth but when I click a button to go to the third the text is not saved how can I save the string when I pass it?

i try to pass the text that i get from second activity to all the others with Intent:

```
 //While on MainActivity
 Intent Second = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 startActivity(Second);

 //While on SecondActivity
 Intent Third = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
 Third.putExtra("Third", String);
 startActivity(Third);

 //While on ThirdActivity
 TextView String;
 String = findViewByID(R.id.TextView1);
 String.setText(string);
 String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("Third");

 Intent Forth = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, ForthActivity.class);
 Forth.putExtra("Forth", string);
 startActivity(Forth);
```

And i passing strings like that until Activity 5 that has a button that goes to the third and the textview text is not saved

I expected when I click the button from activity 5 that goes to the third activity the text view on third activity to be the text from the second activity that I pass it.

Comment: First of all, change your TextView "String" to something else. Because in the current situation the compiler takes it as a data type and not a variable.

Comment: @GauravMall - I imagine the clash only exists in the SO example; triple50 - You should use lower-camel-case for variables. Only classes start with uppercase. (I'll edit your example to remove the clash!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Forward all Extras

You can "forward" all extras using [putExtras(intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.content.Intent)):

```
Intent third = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
third.putExtras(getIntent());
third.putExtra("THIRD", myString);
```

This will maintain the same key at every step, so if you backtrack (Activity 5 => Activity 3) you can still extract the relevant values for that activity.

### Bonus: Use constants to avoid typos

Since your extras might be read in multiple Activities, I would define constants in the final Activity in your flow (I assume a summary or confirmation activity):

```
public class LastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "EXTRA_NAME"
    public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "EXTRA_EMAIL"
    public static final String EXTRA_BOOKING_ID = "EXTRA_BOOKING_ID"

    // rest of class
}
```

Then you don't risk typos when you `putExtra` or `getXxxExtra`:

```
String name = intent.getStringExtra(LastActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
```

Comment: @GauravMall - (I believe) the OP is asking to forward values (as extras) through a chain of activities (presumably collecting additional extras at each step).